# Simplifying this exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-analysis, exponentiation

I am wondering how does

$$\frac{{{e^{zk}}}}
{{{z^2} + 1}} = \frac{1}
{{2i}}\left( {\frac{{{e^{zk}}}}
{{z - i}} - \frac{{{e^{zk}}}}
{{z + i}}} \right)?$$

I can see that $z^2 + 1 = (z + i)(z − i)$, but where does $\frac{1}{2i}$ come from?

Answer (score 6):

Note that for any $a,b\neq0$,
$$\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}=\frac{b}{ab}-\frac{a}{ab}=\frac{b-a}{ab}.$$
Thus, with $a=z-i$ and $b=z+i$,
$$\frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{1}{z+i}=\frac{(z+i)-(z-i)}{(z-i)(z+i)}=\frac{2i}{(z-i)(z+i)}=\frac{2i}{z^2+1}.$$
Thus
$$\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{1}{z+i}\right)=\frac{1}{z^2+1},$$
and multiplying both sides by $e^{zk}$ we have that
$$\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{e^{zk}}{z-i}-\frac{e^{zk}}{z+i}\right)=\frac{e^{zk}}{z^2+1}.$$

Comment: @Thomas, for more generality, Google `partial fraction`.

Comment: Thanks, I just didnt realise I should use partial fractions to derive this.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle \frac{a}{z-i}+\frac{b}{z+i}=\frac{a(z+i)+b(z-i)}{z^2-i^2}=\frac{(a+b)z+(a-b)i}{z^2+1}$.

If you want this to be equal to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{z^2+1}$ for any $z$ you will need $a+b=0$ and $(a-b)i=1$.
I'll let you solve this system.

Comment: Thanks, I just didnt realise I should use partial fractions to solve this!